# heroku node static files path different to localhost

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, heroku

I have a simple node server, serving an html page that loads a js file

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
process.env.PWD = process.cwd();

const port = process.env.PORT || 8000;
app.use(express.static(process.env.PWD + '/public'));
app.use((req, res) => res.sendFile(`${process.env.PWD}/public/index.html`));
app.listen(port);
```

This works locally fine, however when I deploy to Heroku, the request for the js file just loads the html page again. 
The index.html that is also in public folder:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Lynk & Co</title>
</head>
<body>

<div id="root" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="./animations.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Which JS file? Your request handler serves index.html for every request that is not in /public. What does it serve locally?

Comment: so index and js files are both in public folder. I need the index to load the js files. This setup works locally but not on Heroku

Comment: what is the URL you are using to access localhost and what is the URL when you access in heroku(you can give fake domain if you want to)

Comment: http://localhost:8000/ and https://my-app.herokuapp.com/

Comment: how can I serve the html page for every url, but still allow the index to load its javascript?